# flex select value from Combo

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

My goal is to create a generic function that selects a value in a combobox accoring to a value.
(My comoBox holds arrayCollection as dataProvider.)

The difficulty is infact to get a propertyname in runtime mode

```
public function selectComboByLabel(combo:ComboBox , propetryName:String, value:String):void {
    var dp:ArrayCollection = combo.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;
    for (var i:int=0;i<dp.length;i++) {
        if (dp.getItemAt(i).propertyName==value) {
            combo.selectedIndex = i;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

the line if (dp.getItemAt(i).propertyName==value)
is of course incorrect.
It should be arther something like: dp.getItemAt(i).getPropertyByName(propertyName)

Any clue on how to that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Object Property notation.  Do this:

```
dp.getItemAt(i)[propertyName]
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Flextras said, you could also redo your `for` loop to make it easier to read:

```
for each(var item:Object in dp) {
      if(item[propertyName] == value) {
          combo.selectedItem = item;
          return;
      }
  }
```